# How to use RCM theming Library for C# Winform Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reference

I have Downloaded the RCM Library from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RCM.aspx but i don't know how to add the controls that it provides to c# toolbox or how to use the custom form it provides.Guys Plz Help me Out.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions can be derive every control you need with your own class inside your project . After rebuild you SHOULD see them in toolbox.